# How to get a data from two tables at a time PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PDO statemaent like this:

```
$memberList = $conn->prepare("SELECT `id`, `name`, `designantion`,`phone`,`unit_id`, `email` FROM members ORDER BY id ASC");
```

Here `unit_id` is a foreign key so I want to get `unit name` according to the `unit_id`.

I am a beginner in PHP. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Use inner join in your query

Comment: Foreign key into what other table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `jOIN`. Assuming the table that `unit_id` is a foreign key to is named `units`, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT m.id, m.name, m.designation, m.phone, m.unit_id, u.unit_name
FROM members AS m
JOIN units AS u ON u.unit_id = m.unit_id
ORDER BY m.id ASC
```